# Python Unittest to check input within while loop

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am new to python unit testing and I've has some success, but I am stuck on on this one unit test. I am trying to just try to check the input method named `item` and mock the input. I am not receiving any test results back. I am most likely doing it wrong, so any help would be awesome. Here is the code that is being tested

```
def get_input():

  myList = []
  popMax = 6


  while len(myList) < popMax:

    item = input("Enter a number: ")

    if item == "exit":
      break

 else:
    myList.append(item)
    print(myList)

print("This is your list!")
print(myList)
```

and here is the Test suite

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from get_input import *

class GetInputTest(unittest.TestCase):
  @patch('builtins.input', return_value='yes')
  def test_answer_yes(self, input):
    self.assertEqual(get_input(), 'yes')




if __name__ == "__main__":
  unittest.main()
```

Thank you everyone in advanced

Comment: looks like "return item" has only one indent, it should has two indents to be sure included in while loop. otherwise, you will get infinite loop in while since no one change len of myList.

Comment: I usually don't include the `return item` in the while loop. I just did it for the purpose of the Testsuite @CaffHuang

Comment: Since you captured input value in while loop, it cannot be seen outside the loop. You have to pass it out (maybe added into myList) from while loop before returning it.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is an infinite loop (at least in the context of your test case). Indeed the only way to get out of the loop is to get an input being "exit", which does not happen in your test case.

Also, it's not clear how get_input() works, as you define popMax and myList but none of those is actually used in the function... Maybe you want to do myList.append(item) in the loop?

Comment: Hey I updated my code. I knew about the myList.append(item), I guess I was just looking to test the input only so I didn't post the full code. Take a look at the edited code. I want to be able to run a test case to test 'item = input("Enter a Number: ")` I mock the input and ran the test but I get nothing. Not even an error. @GHL

Answer (score 0):

it should be the way your run the test. Here's my test code, and run the test manually. it run as expected since 'yes' will not fulfill the 'exit' test and you will get 6 items in the list.

```
def get_input():
    myList = []
    popMax = 6
    while len(myList) < popMax:
        item = input("Enter a number: ")
        if item == "exit":
            break
        else:
            myList.append(item)
            print(myList)
    print("This is your list!")
    print(myList)

class GetInputTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('builtins.input', return_value='1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n')
    def test_answer_yes(self, input):
        self.assertEqual(get_input(), 'yes')

>>> a = GetInputTest()    
>>> a.test_answer_yes()
['yes']
['yes', 'yes']
['yes', 'yes', 'yes']
['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes']
['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes']
['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes']
This is your list!
['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    a.test_answer_yes()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/mock.py", line 1136, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 4, in test_answer_yes
    self.assertEqual(get_input(), 'yes')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 797, in assertEqual
    assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 790, in _baseAssertEqual
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: None != 'yes'
```

Comment: Awesome. So it works as expected but the test comes back as a fail. Can you give me an example with the test passing using the same run code?